# How could my shell script operate on files in a different folder?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two folders, A and B. In folder A, I have a data file. In folder B, I have program files.  I want the programs in folder B to operate on the file in folder A, running from folder B.

The only way I could come up with was a script that moves the file from A to B, runs the commands from folder B on the file, then moves the output file from B back to A. Is there anyway that I could keep the file in folder A and run the programs from B?

Here is my script right now.  It is very messy, and I think there should be a cleaner way of doing it.

```
echo "Signing with test keys....";
     mv *.apk $HOME/signapk/files/not_signed.apk;
     cd $HOME/signapk/files;
     java -jar signapk.jar testkey.x509.pem testkey.pk8 not_signed.apk signed_apk.apk;
     mv not_signed.apk $HOME/signapk/original.apk;
     mv signed_apk.apk $HOME/signapk/test_signed.apk;;
  2) echo "Signing with private keys....";
     mv *.apk $HOME/signapk/files/not_signed.apk;
     cd $HOME/signapk/files;
     java -jar signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 not_signed.apk signed_apk.apk;
         mv not_signed.apk $HOME/signapk/original.apk;
     mv signed_apk.apk /$HOME/signapk/private_signed.apk;;
  3) echo "Press enter to contintue with zipaligning";
     read ;
     mv *.apk $HOME/signapk/files/zipalign.apk;
     cd $HOME/signapk/files;
     ./zipalign -v -f 4 zipalign.apk zipaligned.apk;
     mv zipaligned.apk $HOME/signapk/zipaligned;
     mv zipalign.apk $HOME/signapk/original.apk;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! All you you have to do is append the path to the file.
Thus:

```
java -jar signapk.jar nameof.apk
```

becomes:

```
java -jar ./path/to/signapk.jar nameof.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) -from your temporary directory B to your other directory A- with the [ln -s](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ln.htm) command?

So you could first create a new empty directory

```
mydir=$(mktemp -d)
```

ask your shell to clean it up at exit

```
trap "rm -rf $mydir" EXIT
```

then you could fill it with symlinks

```
ln -s *.apk $mydir
```

at last run your program there

```
cd $mydir
yourprog *.apk
```

etc. Feel free to adapt that to your needs.

Comment: No, I didn't know about those. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand them correctly, wouldn't that create a file in folder A with a symlink to a program in folder B? At that rate, I could just have the programs from folder B in folder A. But I want them in folder B with nothing in folder A, or is that just not possible with a shell script? I know you can do it with a batch file.

Comment: Turns out it was way easier then I thought. All I have to do if the program is in a different folder is add the path.
So:
java -jar signapk.jar 
becomes:
java -jar ./files/signapk.jar